# Runtime error due to variables being local not global

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error

The following code asks the user to choose a shape, enter the dimensions for said shape, and display its volume.

When I run the code I get the following output, showing me the result is not a number (NaN) :[image]

I realise this must have something to do with the fact my variables are local not global, and that the following function calls:

```
choice = ReadInputShapeChoice();
readshapedimension(choice);
result = CalculateBasicVolume(choice);
```

Are not passing the required data. Have tried to get around this and put the variables in the correct place but to no avail, I am a beginner at using any form of coding language and found the whole program fairly challenging to create.

I have posted a similar question but this is much more detailed, if anyone can shed any light on how I modify the location of my variables in order for the program to run correctly I would be very grateful. Thank you.

The full code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double height, width, length, radius, base_area, result;

 //Function prototypes

int ReadInputShapeChoice();
void readshapedimension(int choice);
float CalculateBasicVolume(int choice);
void PrintResult(int choice);

double rectangular_solid(double length1, double width1, double height1);
double cylinder(double radius2, double height2);
double cone(double radius3, double height3);
double sphere(double radius4);
double square_based_pyramid(double height5, double base_area5);

//function definitions
double rectangular_solid(double length1, double width1, double height1)
{
    double value;
    value = (length1 * width1 * height1);
    return value;
}
double cylinder(double radius2, double height2)
{
    double value;
    value = (3.14159 * (radius2 * radius2) * height2);
    return value;
}
double cone(double radius3, double height3)
{
    double value;
    value = ((3.14159 * (radius3 * radius3) * height3) / 3);
    return value;
}
double sphere(double radius4)
{
   double value;
   value = ((3.14159 * (radius4 * radius4 * radius4))*(4 / 3));
   return value;
}
double square_based_pyramid(double height5, double base_area5)
   {
   double value;
   value = ((height5 * base_area5) * (1 / 3));
   return value;
   }


int ReadInputShapeChoice()
{   int choice;
    cout << "Choose what shape you want to calculate" << endl;
    cout << "1 = Rectangular solid" << endl;
    cout << "2 = Cylinder" << endl;
    cout << "3 = Cone" << endl;
    cout << "4 = Sphere" << endl;
    cout << "5 = Square based pyramid" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void readshapedimension(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int length, width, height;
        cout << "You have chosen rectuangular solid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for length width and height" << endl;
        cin >> length >> width >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cylinder" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cone" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        int radius;
        cout << "You have chosen sphere" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the radius" << endl;
        cin >> radius;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        int height, base_area;
        cout << "You have chosen square based pyramid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter height and area of the base" << endl;
        cin >> height >> base_area;
        break;
    }
    }
}

float CalculateBasicVolume(int choice)
{
switch (choice)
{
    int result;
case 1:
{
    result = rectangular_solid(length, width, height);
    break;
}
case 2:
{
    result = cylinder(radius, height);
    break;
}
case 3:
{
    result = cone(radius, height);
    break;
}
case 4:
{
    result = sphere(radius);
    break;
}
case 5:
{
    result = square_based_pyramid(height, base_area);
    break;
}
    return result;
    }
}
void PrintResult(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
case 1:
{
    cout << "The volume of the rectangular solid is " << result << endl;
    break;
}
case 2:
{
    cout << "the volume of the cylinder is " << result << endl;
    break;
}
case 3:
{
    cout << "The volume of the cone is " << result << endl;
    break;
}
case 4:
{
    cout << "The volume of the sphere is " << result << endl;
    break;
}
case 5:
{
    cout << "the volume of the square based pyramid is " << result <<     endl;
    break;
}

}
}



int main() {
    int choice;
    choice = ReadInputShapeChoice();
    readshapedimension(choice);
    result = CalculateBasicVolume(choice);
    PrintResult(choice);

        return 0;
}}
```

Comment: Inside your case blocks the variables you read in using cin fail to exist when the block goes out of scope.

Comment: ***I realise this must have something to do with the fact my variables are local not global,*** The problem is the narrow scope you define them in. Don't declare these inside your switch. Get all of your declarations outside the switch statements. Also get rid of the globals and pass variables when you need to.

Comment: You get the runtime error because you end up using the globals that you never initialized. They have no relation or connection to the same named variables in the case statements.

Comment: Okay I have deleted the variable declarations contained within the function definition void readshapedimension(int choice). so now they are only declared at the top so I am assuming they are now global. I am still getting the same result as the one shown in the print screen, what else must I do to get this to work ? like I say ANY help is very much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for days and its really eating into my schedule.

Comment: @drescherjm , how do I solve this ? the variables are initialised at the start of the program, do I need to initialise them again ? Thankyou for your help  this far

Comment: This is a job for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring within your functions; this causes the functions to use their local values rather than the globals, as an example I've commented out the re-declarations in your `reshapedimensions` function:

```
// This is our global declaration
double height, width, length, radius, base_area, result;

void readshapedimension(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        // Take out our local declarations
        // Otherwise cin below will write to the local and these values
        // will subsequently be lost when the function exits
        //int length, width, height;
        cout << "You have chosen rectuangular solid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for length width and height" << endl;
        cin >> length >> width >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        //int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cylinder" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        //int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cone" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        //int radius;
        cout << "You have chosen sphere" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the radius" << endl;
        cin >> radius;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        //int height, base_area;
        cout << "You have chosen square based pyramid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter height and area of the base" << endl;
        cin >> height >> base_area;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

I notice, however, that you are using `int` within the function and `double` in your global declaration; if this was intentional you would need to include a conversion somewhere and store the result back to the globals.

It's a good idea to keep your global names unique so you won't get them confused with locals; common techniques are to use `ALLCAPS` or a prefix such as `glob_myvar`.

Comment: Yes this has certainly helped, and my program is successfully running! thank you very much, also thank you for taking the time to inform me about pointers and classes. They are covered in my next workshop although im sure your description will aid the standardised university description, written by a russian who knows only coding language and not english . Thanks again buddy that is an enormous help :)

Comment: No problem. I did start a long winded explanation of how to use classes to do it -- they're kind of what C++ is all about -- but my answer would be a text book. I do recommend you look into [Dynamic Memory Allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) and [Inheritance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) as they'd really help you out making code like this a lot more re-usable and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the *result* variable.

At the top of your file you declare it;

```
double result;
```

But you never initialize it, instead you redefine it later and put the value you want to print out in this new variable;

```
float CalculateBasicVolume(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        int result;
```

The variable you print later is the uninitialized double and not the int which actually contains the volume of the cone.

Comment: Thank you, I have gone ahead and deleted the second initialisation, so that 'double result' is only declared at the top. However I am still getting the same run time error. Please would you know why this is ?